# How to make multiple cURL requests to the same URL?

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

I need to make 8 requests to an API using cURL, each request will only change the `'data' => " Text "`  parameter, I thought of simply replicating the code 8 times, but that doesn't seem like a good solution and can make my code very messy .

Currently my code is like this:

```
$url = 'https://www.paraphraser.io/paraphrasing-api';
$ch = curl_init($url);



$data = array(
            'key' => '526a099f61fdfdffdf8f27fa815129f87f',
            'data' => "SIGNIFICADO: Sonhar com arvores cheia de flores mostra que você precisa reavaliar suas decisões e objetivos. Você está tentando se encaixar nos ideais de outra pessoa. Talvez você esteja se esforçando demais para impressionar os outros. Você precisa trabalhar mais e por mais tempo para alcançar seus objetivos. Talvez você precise fazer um pouco mais de esforço em relação a algum relacionamento.",
            'lang' => 'br',
            'mode' => '3',
            'style' => '0'
        );

$headers = array(
    'Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8',
);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);



$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

How could I make 8 requests and leave my code clean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your code inside a function loop through data value inside a foreach.

```
foreach ($datas as $data) {
curlAPI($data);
}


function curlAPI($data) {
$url = 'https://www.paraphraser.io/paraphrasing-api';
$ch = curl_init($url);



$data = array(
            'key' => '526a099f61fdfdffdf8f27fa815129f87f',
            'data' => $data,
            'lang' => 'br',
            'mode' => '3',
            'style' => '0'
        );

$headers = array(
    'Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8',
);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);



$result = curl_exec($ch);

return $result;
}
```